# Python Gtk3 Box doesn't hide

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm writing an application. It has a sidebar, which I want to be shut on startup. I have tried using `self.sidebarbox.hide()`. This only seems to work when I put it in a function that is linked to a button. When I press the button it shows/hides. How can I fix this?

Here is my code (It's written in python3 but will run in python2.):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio
from gi.repository import WebKit

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Resolution")
        self.set_border_width(0)
        self.set_default_size(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

        hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        hb.props.show_close_button = True
        hb.props.title = "Resolution"
        hb.props.subtitle = "Digital Maths Revision Guide"
        self.set_titlebar(hb)

        button = Gtk.Button()   
        icon = Gio.ThemedIcon(name="emblem-system-symbolic")
        image = Gtk.Image.new_from_gicon(icon, 1)
        button.add(image)
        button.connect("clicked", self.sidebarShowHide)
        button.set_focus_on_click(False)
        hb.pack_start(button)  

        self.sidebarbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=0)
        toplevelbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=0)

        self.add(toplevelbox)

        toplevelbox.pack_start(self.sidebarbox, False, False, 0)

        self.searchentry = Gtk.SearchEntry()
        self.searchentry.connect("search-changed", self.search_changed)
        self.sidebarbox.pack_start(self.searchentry, False, False, 0)

        label = Gtk.Label("Contents Selector")
        self.sidebarbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)

        scroller = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        content = WebKit.WebView()
        scroller.add(content)
        toplevelbox.pack_start(scroller, True, True, 0)

        content.open("/home/oliver/resolution/placeholder.html")

        #This should make the sidebar hide.        
        self.sidebarbox.hide()

    #This works. The sidebar does show/hide.
    def sidebarShowHide(self, button):
        if self.sidebarbox.get_visible():
            self.sidebarbox.hide()
        else:
            self.sidebarbox.show()

    def search_changed(self, searchentry):
        pass




win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `show_all()` which changes the state of all contained widgets to visible, including the sidebar.

If you still like to use it (it's convenient after all) one way is you're own method, which will hide the sidebar after showing all, e.g:

```py
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio
from gi.repository import WebKit

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Resolution")
        self.set_border_width(0)
        self.set_default_size(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

        hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        hb.props.show_close_button = True
        hb.props.title = "Resolution"
        hb.props.subtitle = "Digital Maths Revision Guide"
        self.set_titlebar(hb)

        button = Gtk.Button()
        icon = Gio.ThemedIcon(name="emblem-system-symbolic")
        image = Gtk.Image.new_from_gicon(icon, 1)
        button.add(image)
        button.connect("clicked", self.sidebarShowHide)
        button.set_focus_on_click(False)
        hb.pack_start(button)

        self.sidebarbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=0)
        toplevelbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=0)

        self.add(toplevelbox)

        toplevelbox.pack_start(self.sidebarbox, False, False, 0)

        self.searchentry = Gtk.SearchEntry()
        self.searchentry.connect("search-changed", self.search_changed)
        self.sidebarbox.pack_start(self.searchentry, False, False, 0)

        label = Gtk.Label("Contents Selector")
        self.sidebarbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)

        scroller = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        content = WebKit.WebView()
        scroller.add(content)
        toplevelbox.pack_start(scroller, True, True, 0)

        content.open("/home/oliver/resolution/placeholder.html")

    def inital_show(self):
        win.show_all()
        self.sidebarbox.hide();

    #This works. The sidebar does show/hide.
    def sidebarShowHide(self, button):
        if self.sidebarbox.get_visible():
            self.sidebarbox.hide()
        else:
            self.sidebarbox.show()

    def search_changed(self, searchentry):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = MainWindow()
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.inital_show()
    Gtk.main()
```

Note the `initial_show()` method, and calling it from the main section.